# Good reasons to use Models in zf2?

Tags: model, zend-framework2

I was re-factoring my code on a zf2 project, and I notice that using of Model classes (Entity) was not really necessary. 
For example a typical model is (and it has no other methods inside):

```
namespace Application\Model\Entity;
use Application\Model\Entity;

    class User extends Entity{

        const DB_TYPE = 'main';
        public $id;
        public $username;
        public $password;
        public $is_super;


        public function exchangeArray($data)
        {
            $this->id     = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
            $this->username = (isset($data['username'])) ? $data['username'] : null;
            $this->password = (isset($data['password'])) ? $data['password'] : null;
            $this->is_super = (isset($data['is_super'])) ? $data['is_super'] : null;

        }
    }
```

And a repository method will be:

```
public function fetchAllOrdered($orderby, $asc_desc='asc')
{
    $select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
    $select->from( 'user' );
    $select->columns(array('*'))->order($orderby.' '.$asc_desc);

    return $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
}
```

I notice that tableGateway does not need the model definition (for select/insert/update), in any case it will return an ArrayObject when selecting from the user table. And in the most cases when doing joins or custom queries model is not used.

For example a drawback I have is that if I update a table (adding or removing columns) I should also update the model.

- Why should I use models?
- What are the advantages?
- Does the model affects the performance of a query?

Comment: This is quite a broad question; certainly not specific to ZF2. There is of course an overhead (set up time/performance) of using an object based representation of the database (you would need to map the columns/values of a database query to an entity). As you have noted this certainly adds complexity to your application. However, the downsides are generally regarded as acceptable as you will be able manipulate your domain data using *objects* (think encapsulation, inheritance etc) rather than plain values. I would suggest doing more research on the 'benefits of object relational mappers'.

Comment: [cont].. In a simple application you may decide the downsides (there are many) of an ORM outweigh the benefits you gain. Only you can gage this on a per-project basis. However, In my experience, ZF2 makes it very easy to integrate support for existing ORM's such as Doctrine 2 .

Comment: I am using the basic tablegateway in the zf2, I decide to avoid doctrine2 since it was a performance killers in some projects and with a lot of overhead. Even the tablegatway it self adds some overhead but overrideing the executeSelect we solved some performance problem. The problem is that we have define model for every table, but seems completely useless. Most of logic of the application are done in the repositories and in the services

Comment: "benefits of object relational mappers" this term was missing to me in the search. thank you